# Local smoothing in R

Tags: r, filtering, noise, smoothing, loess

I am struggling with the cleaning of my data. I have a big amount of reflectance curves that become very noisy moving from the center to the corners. The area from 1000 to 1950nm is generally very clean but moving from 1000 to 350 and from 1950 to 2500 I am getting an increasing level of noise.
Here the example of a couple of curves:
[image]

I tried a range of different smoothing methods like loeless, moving average and SavinzkyGolay but the problem is that if I try to increase the smoothing factors to smooth the noisy part also the clean part is affected.
This is the best result I obtained so far:
[image]

As you can see the noisy part isn't smooth yet. However further smoothing will smooth also the central part.
Is there any package in R that would be able to get rid of the noise only locally to obtain something like this?
[image]

[This is a subset of my data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q_cJuhUau2pAGFk-WeVa3_4sPHodBdzC/view?usp=sharing). Sorry, even one single curve is a lot of points so I couldn't post it here in any other way!

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas; Can you apply the smoothing function to only the noisy portion?

Is it possible to set high and low thresholds, and simply exclude or drop all results above and below?